# VB.NET - Insert row into DataView or DataGrid at specific index

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagrid, dataview

I have a **DataView** full of rows. That data is being sorted and filtered before being used as a source for a **DataGrid** that is printed to a webpage. Sometimes, there are pairs of rows that should be grouped together even though they're not in perfect sort order. My problem is that I don't know how to delete the row from wherever it falls in the default sort and re-insert it at a different index.

For example, suppose I have this data:

```
App# | Name | State | Status | Creator | LinkID
______________________________________________
1001 | Joe  |  LA   |  New   |  User1  | 1234
0123 | Jan  |  NE   | Closed |  User2  | 
0455 | Sue  |  NY   |  New   |  User3  | 1234
0080 | Bob  |  CA   | Closed |  User4  | 
0001 | Ron  |  ND   |  New   |  User5  |
```

I need the two rows with LinkID `1234` grouped together at all times. So if the user sorts by Name, for example, this is what we get:

```
App# | Name | State | Status | Creator | LinkID
______________________________________________
0080 | Bob  |  CA   | Closed |  User4  | 
0123 | Jan  |  NE   | Closed |  User2  | 
1001 | Joe  |  LA   |  New   |  User1  | 1234
0455 | Sue  |  NY   |  New   |  User3  | 1234
0001 | Ron  |  ND   |  New   |  User5  |
```

Notice how `Sue` is out of order. In order to accomplish this, I need to loop back through the data after it's been sorted and move any linked rows up to their match.

My idea to do that looked like this:

```
Dim dvSource As DataView = DS.Tables("Request").DefaultView
dvSource.Sort = sortString
dvSource.RowFilter = filterString

dgGrid.DataSource = dvSource
dgGrid.DataBind()

'Loop through datagrid and move linked rows together
For i = 0 To dgGrid.Items.Count - 1
    If dgGrid.Items(i).Cells(5).Text <> "&nbsp;" Then
        For j As Integer = i + 1 To dgGrid.Items.Count - 1
            If dgGrid.Items(i).Cells(5).Text = dgGrid.Items(j).Cells(5).Text Then
                Dim row As DataGridItem = dgGrid.Items(j)
                'Remove row from dgGrid
                'Insert row into dgGrid at new index
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

How do I remove the row from `dgGrid` and insert at the new index?

Answer (score 0):

To remove and insert rows you can use this code:

```
Dim Row as DataRow
Row = dgGrid.Rows(x) 'Where x is the index of the row you want to remove
dgGrid.Rows.Remove(Row)
dgGrid.Rows.InsertAt(row, y) 'Where y is the index where you want the row to be inserted
```

Comment: `Rows` is not a member of `DataGrid`.

Comment: try adding `Imports System.Data` at the top of your project

Comment: It's already there. Visual Studio also happens to be telling me the Imports statement is unnecessary...

Comment: The MSDN also doesn't show any reference to a Rows property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The OP's grid is using an `Items` collection.   It's a different grid than a DataGridView.

Comment: It's a DataGrid, not a DataGridView.

Comment: and what if you send your datagrid to a datatable, I think is much easier to use/edit.